# why does isdigit() returns false when it has space between numbers and how to solve it

Tags: python

Does isdigit function in python only returns True when numbers are connected? or do they count space between numbers as string? I wrote a very simple code(the first one) and I want it to detect as a number and then turn them into English from decimal ascii code. If first and second examples are unable to solve with isdigit, then is there any other ways to solve second code?

```py
a="1 2 3" 
print(a.isdigit())
```

```py
while True:
    x=input("type letter or numbers:")
    if x.isdigit()==0:
        x=x.split()
        for i in range(len(x)):
            b=x[i]
            print(chr(int(b)),end="")
        print()

    else:
        break
```

Comment: `str.isdigit` returns `True` only if all of the characters in the string are digits. Whitespace characters are not digits.

Comment: A regular expression can help.

Comment: You can replace spaces with an empty string. `x.replace(" ", "")` ??

Comment: If you want to convert from space-delimited ASCII numbers to "english" chars, you can use something like this `english = ''.join([chr(int(i)) for i in string.split(' ')])`

Comment: `x.isdigit()==1` makes no sense. `isdigit` returns a boolean value, it never returns `1`. The result is *convertible* to one but it’s nonsense to compare it like this.

Comment: you can also simplify the loop with i to `for y in x: print(chr(int(y)),end="")`

Answer (score 3):

Short answer : `isdigit()` check `ascii` value at every index. If any `char` is not in `[0,9]` it will return `False` otherwise true.
If you want to extract all number from a string then you can use simple regex

```
import re
yourNumber = int(re.compile("(\d+)").match('12324  2').group(1)))
#output = 123242
```

Warning : this will ignore all character present in string concate all your numbers and convert it into number

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach similar to OP's original code.  The things is, you bneed to check `isdigit()` on each character.  If you check `isdigit()` only on the whole string, this will make it so the code discards any string, unless it is ONLY digits.

```
def find_digits(str):
    for c in str:
        if c.isdigit():
            print('{} = {}'.format(c, ord(c)))

#yield:
>>> find_digits('1234')
1 = 49
2 = 50
3 = 51
4 = 52
>>> find_digits('1 w 3 5')
1 = 49
3 = 51
5 = 53
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with `isdigit()` is that you are using it on the whole string instead of the individual numbers, which are separated by spaces.

Here's some code to convert from space-delimited ASCII numbers to letters.

I would also write this as a function and use a string to store the result instead of calling `print()` directly every iteration.

```py
loop = True

while loop:
    # a list of each value entered by the user, split on spaces
    line = input('type letters or numbers').split(' ')
    
    # iterate through the values
    for x in line:
        # only process if the user entered a number
        # here isdigit is used on individual values (the numbers) and not the
        # whole string, so you don't get the issue with spaces not counting as
        # digits
        if x.isdigit():
            print(chr(int(x)), end='')
        # exit the loop if the user enters something that isn't a digit
        else:
            loop = False
            break
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a replacement function — essentially a one-liner — that does what you want:

```
def is_digit(s):
    """Return True if all characters in the string are digits or space characters."""
    return s.replace(' ', '').isdigit()

a = "1 2 3"
print(is_digit(a))  # -> True
```